# How to determine if form is docked?

Tags: window, state, docking, c++builder-xe

How to determine in C++ Builder XE, if window is currently docked? All windows in my application are derived from base class TForm. How to catch change from docked to undocked state and vice versa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Form's `HostDockSite` property will be non-`NULL` when docked, an `NULL` otherwise.

There is no specific notification for when the `HostDockSite` changes, but you can override the form's virtual `Dock()` and/or `DoDock()` methods to check if the `HostDockSite` changes when calling the inherited methods.  Alternatively, override the Form's virtual `SetParent()` method and check for the `csDocking` flag in the Form's `ControlState` property.